# Can I make hole above a lintel for a flue

Tags: structural, flue

I'm doing some work on a flat and want to move the boiler higher up than it is. That means putting a flue above the window. The problem is I'm the second to top floor flat. As you can see from the picture attached, I have three options. Ideally, I would like to do **B** and put a hole above the lintel and board up the window from the inside - although due to the available space indoors, I may have to cut a little through the lintel (see the second attached picture to see the inside). This option, I guess I'd need a structural engineer to see if it's even possible, or does it not matter because the whole for a flue will be fairly small?

The second idea would be to brick up the window like they've done in the flat marked **A**, which I'd obviously just need permission from the landlord (the property is leasehold in the UK, so permission is required from the management company).

I've searched quite a bit around and not found too much information on this so any pointers in what I'm doing would be greatly appreciated! I guess my questions are:

1. can I even do **B** and put the flue above/through the lintel?
2. is there an advantage to do either option?
3. can you see any issues with what I'm trying to do?

[image: picture of outside]

[image: picture of inside]